# Wrapping text next to image on right side

Tags: html, css

The text doesn't want to wrap on the right side of the image.
It is supposed to be against it on the right side with a little bit of spacing in between it.

This is what the bar is supposed to look like and underneath has to be a spacer (line) https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGIHz.png which is gonna be style 14 on this link https://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ozinB

Hopefully anyone can help me.

Snippet:

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:block;
  width: 65%;
}

#statistics_background {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

.statistics_header {
  margin: 15px;
}

.summoners_name {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
  <a href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="statistics_background">
    <div class="statistics_header">
      <img class="summoners_icon clearfix" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&txt=95%C3%9795&w=95&h=95" alt="Summoners Icon">
      <div class="summoners_name">
        <h3>Summoners Name</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Float your image and text left and apply your clearfix to the the parent, NOT the image. (put it with the containing element). When you clear a property, your clearing below it, not the actual property itself which is being floated. Floating left will collapse your div by breaking the stacking order, but the clearfix will make it better. Floating right does not solve your problem.

Give the divs a width property within the container. I don't want to solve this for you so I'm not writing out the exact code answer. But you want your containing elements to be within the container in terms of width. Remember, width does not account for your padding and margin, so if you want space to be between, you could try something like 28% and 68% with 1% margin and padding. Alternatively you could use the calc parameter(not supported IE8)

Example:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
```

CSS:

```
.container{
 width:100%
};

.img-icon{
width:30%;
float:left;
};

.summoners-name{
width:70%
float:left;
};
```

from your code: -- this example has its own problems - however this just gives you an idea of how you can properly float and clearfix your items to sit properly.

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php define('DeniedAccessFiles', TRUE); ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="logo">
  <a href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div id="statistics_background clearfix">
    <div class="statistics_header">
      <img class="summoners_icon " src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=12&txt=95%C3%9795&w=95&h=95" alt="Summoners Icon">
      <div class="summoners_name">
        <h3>Summoners Name</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 65%;
}

#statistics_background {
  margin:0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 65%;


  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006184 0%, #303142 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

.statistics_header {
 height:150px;  
}

.summoners_name {
  float: left;
  padding:20px;
}
.summoners_icon{
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to get that fixed in the snippet I posted.

Comment: Have you figured it out? Sorry I got busy, and then forgot, one sec i'll copy your code and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly how you wanted it, and I don't  want to write your whole thing for you. But here is an idea on how you can approach. I will edit the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

You floated the text right.

```
.summoners_name {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: If I float it left, that doesn't work either - Then the image gets put on the right side of the text.

Answer (score 0):

you messed up with your anchor tag.You have added an extra ">.

correct it
EDIT:

use
`<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>`

Comment: Where do you see that? I only see the php, but not an extra ">  (this might be because it's a php echo in there to get the homepage url at all times.